# Sending data from Android

Tags: java, php, android

I want to sent the data from an Android device to PHP. I have tried but where I am wrong I don't know. How do I correct this?

This is the Android code that I have done.

```
public class php_connect extends Activity {
    InputStream is;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/food/food.php");
            json.put("id",1);
            json.put("name","john");
            Log.i("jason Object", json.toString());
            httppost.setHeader("json", json.toString());

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            se.setContentType("application/json");
            httppost.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(statusCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            is = se.getContent();
            Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I get response as 200 and connected successfully but cannot see data in PHP.

And my PHP code is:

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json = json_decode($data,true);
    var_dump($json);
    $id=$json['id'];
    echo $id;
?>
```

I always get the null result.

Comment: what does `var_dump($data)`  prints?

Comment: This could mean that you don't have 'special php.ini directives' as hinted in the php manual (see my answer). I am not sure what these special directives are. I recommend trying the alternate method I have suggested

Comment: Yah I have tried your suggestiong but stil not working..of u know the best tutorial regarding this..Please provide me the link...

Comment: Can you show the updated code after trying my suggestion?

Comment: List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonParam", json.toString()));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters);
            formEntity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8"); 
            formEntity.setContentType("multipart/form-data");
            httppost.setEntity(formEntity);  
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Comment: $data = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$json = json_decode($data,true); 
var_dump($json);
echo $_POST['jsonParam'];

Comment: remove the first three lines... just echo the $_post line ...

Comment: <?php echo $_POST["jsonParam"]; ?> yah I have tried but error coming---Undefined Index:jsonParam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> In case of POST requests, it preferrable to $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a potentially less memory intensive alternative to activating always_populate_raw_post_data. php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data"

I think it will be even easier to encode your JSON as a form parameter and use the normal PHP $_POST function to read it:

```
List parameters = new ArrayList();
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonParam", json.toString())
UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters)
httppost.setContentType("multipart/form-data");
httppost.setEntity(formEntity);
```

On the PHP side you can simply do

```
Got <?php echo $_POST["jsonParam"]; ?>!<br />
```

Note: I have not tested the above code.

Comment: <?php echo $_POST["jsonParam"]; ?>  when i try this...error is: UNDEFINED Index